# counting the amount of letter and packages a person received - Python

Tags: python, string

My program should read in a file named mail.txt that looks like this:

```
Jane Fairfax,Letter
Frank Churchill,Letter
Emma Woodhouse,Letter
Frank Churchill,Letter
Harriet Smith,Package
Emma Woodhouse,Letter
Philip Elton,Package
Emma Woodhouse,Package
```

My program should work like this:

```
Name: Emma Woodhouse
2 Letters
1 Package
```

This is my code:

```
q = input("Name: ")
p = open("mail.txt", "r")
name_list = p.readlines()
lista = {}

for i in name_list:
  i = i[:-1]
  name_list = i
```

I don't know how to proceed next. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a homework completion service.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. You want to use that dictionary you created to keep track of all the names you have read and also the type of mail each person has received. Here is what I came up with:

```
tenants = {}

def print_mail(name):
    if name in tenants:
        print 'Name: {}'.format(name)
        print '{} Letters'.format(tenants[name]['Letter'])
        print '{} Packages'.format(tenants[name]['Package'])
    else:
        print 'Name not found'

def read_mail_file():
    # Using the with statement creates a file object and 
    # automatically closes it for you when the statement exits
    with open('mail.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
            # Convert the line into an array split by commas
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            name = line[0]
            mail_type = line[1]

            # If you have not already seen this person then
            # create an embedded dictionary to keep track of their mail
            if name not in tenants:
                tenants[name] = {'Letter': 0, 'Package': 0}

            # Then, just update the type of mail they received on this
            # line
            tenants[name][mail_type] += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_mail_file()
    print_mail('Emma Woodhouse')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

```
import collections
y=[]
with open('mail.txt') as infile:
    counts = collections.Counter(l.strip() for l in infile)
for line, count in counts.most_common():
    y.append(line + ',' + str(count))
line=input("Name: ")
for i in y:
    if line == str(i).split(',')[0]:
        print(str(i).split(',')[2] + ' ' + str(i).split(',')[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

First, we can use a list comprehension to parse the file itself.

```
In [1]: with open("mail.txt") as file:
   ...:     items = [item.split(',') for item in file.read().split('\n')[:-1]]
   ...:     

In [2]: items
Out[2]: 
[['Jane Fairfax', 'Letter'],
 ['Frank Churchill', 'Letter'],
 ['Emma Woodhouse', 'Letter'],
 ['Frank Churchill', 'Letter'],
 ['Harriet Smith', 'Package'],
 ['Emma Woodhouse', 'Letter'],
 ['Philip Elton', 'Package'],
 ['Emma Woodhouse', 'Package']]
```

We can then use *another* comprehension to determine the items that belong to a specific person.

```
In [3]: received = [kind for (name, kind) in items if name == recipient]

In [4]: received
Out[4]: ['Letter', 'Letter', 'Package']
```

We can then use a `Counter` to count the number of each item that was received.

```
In [5]: from collections import Counter

In [6]: Counter(received)
Out[6]: Counter({'Letter': 2, 'Package': 1})

In [7]: totals = dict(Counter(received))

In [8]: totals
Out[8]: {'Letter': 2, 'Package': 1}
```

Finally, we can use a `for` loop to display this in the desired format.

```
In [9]: print("Name:", recipient)
   ...: for (item, count) in totals.items():
   ...:     print(count, item)
   ...:     
Name: Emma Woodhouse
2 Letter
1 Package
```